# Detect frequency value using iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app that should detect a frequency of a certain sound. I based my app on [Pitch Detector](https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector). I imported the files that are in the Pitch Detector example, then I fixed my code to accept this new classes. I post here my code to explain you my issue:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RIOInterface;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL isListening;
    float currentFrequency;
    RIOInterface *rioRef; // HERE I'M GETTING ISSUE
}
- (IBAction)startListenWatermark:(UIButton *)sender;

@property(nonatomic, assign) RIOInterface *rioRef;
@property(nonatomic, assign) float currentFrequency;
@property(assign) BOOL isListening;

#pragma mark Listener Controls
- (void)startListener;
- (void)stopListener;

 - (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@synthesize isListening;
@synthesize rioRef;
@synthesize currentFrequency;

- (IBAction)startListenWatermark:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (isListening) {
        [self stopListener];
    } else {
        [self startListener];
    }
    isListening = !isListening;
}

- (void)startListener {
    [rioRef startListening:self];
}

- (void)stopListener {
    [rioRef stopListening];
}

- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    NSLog(@"FREQUENCY: %f", newFrequency);
}
```

In the code you can see where's my issue and Xcode says: `Existing instance variable 'rioRef' with assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained`. If I delete the row that give this errore the app doesn't calls the method `[rioRef startListening:self];` and `[rioRef stopListening];`.

In the file `RIOInterface.mm` I'm getting another error in line 97 and Xcode suggested me to change it from:

```
RIOInterface* THIS = (RIOInterface *)inRefCon; --> RIOInterface* THIS = (RIOInterface *)CFBridgingRelease(inRefCon);
```

The it gives me this other error on the line 283:

```
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
```

It says me this: `Assigning to 'void' from incompatible type 'RIOInterface *const__strong'`, so I looked to the web and I found this solution:

```
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;
```

I'm not sure if it's right to do so or not, I hope you can help me to solve this issues, thank you in advice.

Comment: What's the declaration of `callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon`?  If that's a C-callback mechanism, then you wouldn't pass it an Objective-C object, would you.

Comment: I guess so, I didn't wrote this part of the code, it's in the library `RIOInterface`

Comment: Try remove line: RIOInterface *rioRef; and also @synthesize rioRef;

Comment: If I remove the line `RIOInterface *rioRef` it never calls the methods `[rioRef startListening:self];` and `[rioRef stopListening];`, so I can't remove it otherwise nothing works

Comment: When will it be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 2nd and the 3rd problem I solved by disabling the ARC for the file in which there are the code I provided above. For the first problem I solved by writing this code:

`rioRef = [RIOInterface sharedInstance];`

Comment: did you find a way to solve the 2nd and 3rd problem without disabling ARC?